# MVC 2.0 c# asp.net 4.0 Instantiate an object from a library shared in the session

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, .net-4.0, controller

I'm trying to use the MVC 2.0 framework to instantiate an object of a library.

I want to be able to instantiate this object every time I navigate my application with a differnt browser (creating new session) and call methods on this object from my controllers mantaining separated the objects of different sessions.

Where do I have to store and instantiate my object?

Thanks

Comment: I've tried to store it in controller class, but it is re-created everytime I recall the controller also with the same browser and I don't know how to retrieve the object from other controllers...

Answer (score 0):

If the object's scope is session then I'd store it in the session cache.

You'll want to test in the controller's constructor if it exists, if not then create and store in the session.